# Kubuntu - Screen Goes Blank After 31 Seconds Of Not Moving Mouse

Tags: kubuntu, dell, screen

I'm a novice at Linux/Ubuntu. I installed Kubuntu and have configured the Power Management and Display And Monitor settings appropriately. I've installed Caffeine, and have tried multiple times to prevent the screen from going blank. I've followed other articles and tried disabling the Screen Blanking feature. I've also disabled all the power saving options.

Issue: After 31 seconds of not moving the mouse, even if multimedia - including web-based multimedia - is still playing, the screen goes blank. Please give me very specific instructions when referring to the Terminal commands and their respective directories.

Thank you in advance.

Troubleshooting performed:
mv ~/.kde ~/.kde.old
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
mv ~/.local ~/.local.old
mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
shutdown -r now
Disabled Hardware Acceleration in Firefox and Chromium
 rm ~/.local/share/kscreen
 sudo killall sddm
Tried New Sessions

xset -q revealed the following:
xset -q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  600    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  20/10    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled

Some Specs:
Kubuntu 16.10
KDE Plasma Version 5.7.5
KDE Frameworks Version 5.26.0
Qt Version 5.6.1
Kernel Version 4.8.0-27-generic
OS Type 64-bit
Dell Latitude E5410

Comment: grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: xset -dpms
xset s noblank